# Upload Image to MongoDb using meteor.js framework

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

> kindly provide me a code to upload image using meteor framework
>   I am clueless about the programmable code

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can find very useful and well documented package on [atmosphere js](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=upload)

In your specific case for upload image i suggest you [okgrow](https://atmospherejs.com/okgrow/image-upload)

Comment: can i also get a demo video where can i have all files made

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at the package CollectionFS and specifically the GridFS storage option.

The GridFS option will store uploaded images in MongoDb as you state in your question.

Here's a link to it: [CFS: GridFS](https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/gridfs)

Here is a link to the base package for CollectionFS. Use this with the above GridFS package.

[CollectionFS Standard Packages](https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/standard-packages)

Comment: CFS is pretty much abandoned since that post. We switched over to  [Slingshot](https://atmospherejs.com/edgee/slingshot) and S3.